# Laravel 5.2 add hidden value in default user registration form

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5

I'm using the standard Laravel 5.2 authentication. And i have implemented one more registration form/view [image]
The question is:

How to add one more form field that is hidden (for example role_id) on each form so that when user is registered it automatically gets a role...
now while writing this i think this could be a security issue...How is this done properly???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the role is the same for any who registers, then I suggest to do that in your controller when creating the user.

```
$user->you_role = your_value;
```

In case you need in in the view, then it should be as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" name="role" value="your_value">
```

Comment: Yes that would be it.....this should not be in view but inside Controller instead!

Answer (score 1):

To add field in registration form first add a hidden field in register view.

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <input type="hidden" name="role" class="form-control" value="customer">                                        
 </div>
```

After this specify your field value in $fillable array, here I have added `role`

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;    

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','role',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token', 
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have the role_id available through blade you can use something like {{ user->role_id}}

```
<input type="hidden" name="role" value="role_id">
```